# Encrypting additional Table columns using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm usingn [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for rails authentication with the bcrypt encryptor for the password column.

I have a User table that stores sensitive information which I would like to encrypt

Is it possible to use devise to encrypt and decrypt other User columns (other than just password)?

Comment: You don't say who should have access to the data: just the user logged in, the administrators, or ...?  The answer to that question determines how you'd encrypt things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [devise_aes_encryptable](https://github.com/chicks/devise_aes_encryptable#readme), its an extension to Devise and has both Encrypt and Decrypt methods.
The rest is upto you how to customize it as per your needs.

I couldn't find a **Module: Devise::Decryptors** in Devise, but there was a [Module: Devise::Encryptors](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Encryptors). So, I propose to use the extension above.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think that this is a good general solution for column encryption.

Comment: I agree, I'm using attr_encrypted

Comment: passwords should in general not be decryptable unless you're writing a password manager