# Devise: Add Hashed Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, devise

I'm using Devise within my Rails app and I want to create a column where a user's pin number is stored (and is hashed).

The pin number is optional so it will be empty by default and changeable on the user settings page, provided by Devise.
I have the following code which works as expected:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

I would add `:pin_number` as one of the permitted parameters in the `account_update_params` function, but how would I hash that and where?

I am a novice with rails so I would be grateful to be shown how to hash the parameter and then save it with the appropriate user.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763160/encrypting-additional-table-columns-using-devise

Comment: Are you sure you want to encrypt it?  Hashing it would be far more secure.

Comment: @Sculper I would rather hash it yes, thanks for the advice. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [bcrypt](http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org/) gem for this (Devise is already using this).  In your create / update actions, you would have something that looks like this:

```
pin_number = BCrypt::Password.create("1234")
```

You'd then store `pin_number` in the database as is.  When you retrieve it, you'd make a new `Bcrypt::Password` object like this:

```
hashed_pin = @user.pin_number
pin_number = BCrypt::Password.new(hashed_pin)
```

You could then compare a raw string to the BCrypt::Password objects with the `==` operator (the string will be automatically hashed before comparison):

```
hashed_pin == "1234" # true
```

In order to use this with your User model, you would need to add the field to your User migration:

```
# devise_create_users.rb
t.string :pin_number
```

You could then access it just like any other attribute of your model:

```
@user = User.find(1)
@user.pin_number = BCrypt::Password.create("1234")
@user.save
```

Comment: How would I save this hashed pin? I know how to retrieve it, but I'm using devise and don't know what to change/add.

Comment: @JoshLukeBlease I've updated my answer.  You would need to add the field to your user migration (or create a new migration to add the pin field).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [***`attr_encrypted`***](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted) gem for this.

```
#user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_encrypted :pin_number, :key => 'a secret key'
end
```

And save encrypted version of `pin_number` in `encrypted_pin_number` field and call it like `@user.encrypted_pin_number` which returns the encrypted value of `pin_number`.